# Why can't I change the key of a localized keyword?

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, blueprint

In Tridion keyword keys can be changed at the global level without any issue. However a localized keyword key cannot be changed and gives the error:

"Unable to save item
Invalid value for property 'Key'. It is not possible to update Key property of a localized item. Current value: a1. New value: a2."

I understand there are always risks when making changes like this but why does Tridion block us from making the change?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: it would be inter sting to understand if there's a 'reason' from the product group as to why this change is blocked. if that's a valid reason then we should add the 'idea' that we don't allow an editor to update it in the first place (i.e. the error is only shown when the editor clicks save - surely the field should be disabled?)

Comment: I would understand the reason to be similar to why you can't change field names when you localize schemas: to ensure that searching for key "TopNavigationRoot" (for instance) always returns the same keyword across websites and languages. As to why an editor is allowed to change it, that does seem like a UI defect (I was able to reproduce this in Web 8.5, FWIW).

Comment: Though not quite from the product group, @paceaux described keyword behavior in his "[the more you know" post](http://blog.frankmtaylor.com/2013/02/21/the-more-you-know-tridion-2011-and-keywords/). In terms of defect versus expected behavior I would also prefer the key is not editable in child Publications. But that should be for _everyone_ and not only _editors_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SDL documentation at [this link states:](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-557E4B29-4922-4864-B9A2-EFDAAE7B683A)

> Key
>
> A text value that is unique across the BluePrint and that can be used to associate an external resource to the Keyword, for example a
>   product ID.

So I guess this answers your question. :) Main idea behind keywords is to classify content **across publications** with same ID. Therefore, changing its key is not something you should, or need to do.

I hope this answers your question :D

Comment: +1, though "value" should be "key" in this answer since Keywords have separate fields for `Value` ("Title"), `Description`, and `Key`. All of them are localizable except for the `Key` field in question.

Comment: Noted :D and changed

Comment: Thanks Mark. Makes sense I was just looking for a bit more of the why behind it which you supplied. Cheers!

Comment: In general, the `Key` is intended as (external) identifier for the Keyword and it does not make sense to change the ID in a different context. Therefore, this is a so-called *non-localizable* property. This means that you cannot change it in a local copy, but it also means that all local copies are kept in sync if the property is changed in the primary parent.